# System.IO.EndOfStreamException: 'Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.'

Tags: c#

**Is there anyone who could help me debug it?**

```
private static bool ValidateFormat(string dumpFile, int magicNumberToSearch)
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(dumpFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
            {
                var magicNumber = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
                var dataLength = binaryReader.ReadInt32();

                return magicNumber == magicNumberToSearch
                       && dataLength == binaryReader.BaseStream.Length;
            }
        }
    }
```

In
var magicNumber = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
am getting exception S**ystem.IO.EndOfStreamException: 'Unable to read beyond the end of the stream**

Thanks lot

Comment: This is not C++, why have you tagged it C++?

Comment: Your code runs without throwing on my machine with a random text file containing a few characters as input. You should probably post your input file

Comment: It looks like the file is empty and you're assuming that it contains at least two integers.

Comment: its binary file containing more data  @JonasHogh

Comment: @PrasannaPrashi You're *assuming* that it contains more data. Your program should check that it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to help you without knowing the input file. But I suspect BinaryReader doesn't work the way you expect. A good strategy might be to try and produce the file format that you want using a BinaryWriter, and see if the output matches your expectations. For instance a program like this one:

```
using (var stream = File.Open("myfile", FileMode.Create))
{
    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8, false))
    {
        int magicNumber = 42;
        writer.Write(magicNumber);
        int len = 100;
        writer.Write(len);
        writer.Write("more stuff");
    }
}
```

This will produce output that looks like this in a hex editor:

[image: hex dump]